# HTTP, side-effect free but not idempotent URL

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization, culture

Imagine a search page with various search parameters (e.g. last name, date of birth). We used a GET-based form and everything worked fine - until now.

Last week we introduced globalization into our application and ran into problems with various fields. The HTTP-GET request is still side-effect free, however, not idempotent anymore - if the user is running under a different culture the collation changes and a different set of matched persons is returned.

**Q1)** Is it still a good idea to use the GET method then?

This globalization-unawareness is also "documented" in the ASP.NET MVC value binders: the `QueryStringValueProvider` uses `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. This provides a well-defined API to all non-UI-clients.

Without regard to question 1 we converted those forms to POST-based forms. The ASP.NET MVC `FormValueProvider` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and model binding is back at work - without that modification we retrieved model binding errors from ASP.NET MVC.

Of course we face the problem now, that a user is not able to click the back button of his browser after searching without retrieving the annoying "are you sure that you want to POST this data again" warning.

**Q2)** Is there a way to tell the browser that for a page it is completely okay to post it again?

If this is not possible, we need to change back to GET-based forms, however, our URL API is not idempotent anymore...something I don't like either - AND requires me to dive deep into the ASP.NET MVC model binding infrastructure to use a culture-aware value provider...

Comment: Surely if the user has changed their culture, then a different GET request is issued, so the idempotency of the GET is not actually in question as there are two distinct GETs?

Comment: So you would recommend to change all those forms to also send the current culture and use a model binder which is aware of that field in the query string and changes its internal culture accordingly?

Comment: I wasn't recommending anything - I was just suggesting that your assumption that the GET request is not idempotent is not correct...

Comment: Currently it is correct...we do not send the current culture to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is side-effect free, it by definition is idem-potent.

You seem to confuse idempotency with "always returns the same thing".

Comment: side-effect free should be "safe", and those two concepts are not the same. E.g. HTTP PUT is not side-effect free but is idempotent.

Comment: Yes. But any side-effect free request is idempotent.